# how to animate a box continually?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have two questions about jquery:

First, how to make a box that move to right -> bottom -> left -> top -> right.... repeatly?

And when mouse hover on div container, box has to be hidden...

here is my source:

```
$(".container").ready(function(){
    $(".box").animate({left:"100px"}, "slow")
           .animate({top:"100px"}, "slow")
           .animate({left:0},"slow")
           .animate({top:0}, "slow");

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TTstW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/TTstW/1/

```
(function loop(){
    $(".box").animate({left:"100px"}, "slow")
           .animate({top:"100px"}, "slow")
           .animate({left:0},"slow")
           .animate({top:0}, "slow", loop);

 })();
```

You can hide the box on hover with CSS:

```
.container:hover .box{
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TTstW/2/